# AVPlayer start buffering PlayerItem before loading it in player

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Does anyone know if there's a way to start buffering AVPlayerItems before they are loaded into the AVPlayer?  I have a group of player items that I want to play in sequence and I don't want there to be any delay between them.

I have tried using AVQueuePlayer which doesn't really seem to help and some people are saying AVQueuePlayer doesn't event pre-buffer the next video in advance.  I have also tried using the AVPlayerItem settings for canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamWhilePaused and preferredForwardBufferDuration and neither of them seem to do anything.  It seems like the playerItem won't actually buffer until it is being played by the AVPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround where I can create multiple AVPlayers instead of using 1 AVPlayer with multiple playerItems.  It seems that once the playerItem is loaded into the AVPlayer that it begins buffering so I just use a separate AVPlayer for each playerItem now and there is no delay.